# How to load a react component in HTML?

Tags: html, reactjs, dom

I am new to using reactjs. I have an html file where i am trying to enter a react component . The react is described in two files: index.js which is "importing" a main.js file. 
i want to have those components in my webpage. Can anyone tell me how can i do it ?

I tried using a script in my html file :

script src="index.js"

but it is not working.

I am totally new to this .

Comment: I suggest to read the following documentation, I hope that helps: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: @norbitrial You have won me by little :))

Answer (score 1):

**Reactjs** is a group of components which bundled together to make a single page app.
I suggest reading the documentation of **Reactjs**

Answer (score 0):

React js library is used to build a single page application. And it is a component-based library. You write your components and then render them into a single HTML div tag.

You should start your react journey with create-react-app boilerplate (https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app).